# Can I restrict android device to only accept specific NFC communications?

Tags: android, nfc

I am developing an app for a uni project that was going to allow users to send data to an office device with NFC but it leaves me with a security concern.

The office device would only be used to collect certain data from multiple users via the beam.  Am I able to restrict that device to only accept data from a certain app?  I wouldn't want them to be able to push pictures,contacts or anything malicious etc onto the device.  All the office device would need to do is receive data from one application.  I was looking to use it as an alternative to wi-fi.

I'm still not very experienced in programming but I figure I would need to restrict the office device on a system level to only accept certain mime-types.  Does the device admin app allow for development of such policies or is that limited to the password/encryption security stuff?  Is NFC all or nothing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I able to restrict that device to only accept data from a certain app?

Only by making your own custom build of Android and installing it on the device as a ROM mod.

> Does the device admin app allow for development of such policies

No, sorry.

> Is NFC all or nothing?

NFC is limited to what the user of the device has in terms of apps that can receive. If the device lacks apps that receive "pictures,contacts or anything malicious", then others cannot beam such content over.

Comment: Yes, but is restricting to the device necessary in this case? His app should only register with an intent filter for only the types of data he wants. If someone sends another type of beam his app would ignore it, if the device has no other nfc apps then it would essentially be the same as restricting the whole device if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thank you.  There would be no need for any other app on the office device but it never crossed my mind to just delete the apps already installed.

Comment: @midders: "it never crossed my mind to just delete the apps already installed" -- you may not be able to delete them, but you may be able to disable them in the Apps section of Settings. Some will be on the device firmware, and unless you're rolling your own firmware, you won't be able to delete those.

Comment: @schwiz: "but is restricting to the device necessary in this case?" -- the OP is the one asking for it, not me. :-)

Comment: The biggest concern, I think, for the scope of this project is possibility someone could send a link to a malicious webpage. I could root or run an updater script and remove Browser.apk and other unwanted apps?

Comment: @midders: Again, you can probably disable them in the Apps area of Settings.

Comment: @CommonsWare sometimes you need to read between the lines of OPs question ;-)

Comment: @CommonsWare but I can't disable the browser to stop someone pushing a url that will be automatically opened in the device.

Comment: There would be the possibility of the public accessing the device.

Comment: @midders: You can certainly disable the browser, through Apps in Settings, at least on some devices (e.g., the Galaxy Nexus I just checked). It's entirely possible that there are some devices that will not let you disable it, and it is entirely possible that the OS has built-in ability to interpret NFC tags for HTTP URLs (though AFAIK that's only handled by browsers).

Comment: Right, I'll see if I can get hold of a nexus.  It doesn't allow me to disable the browser on my s3 or the htc I was given by the uni.